# Django Filterset object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to use a custom filterset class with DjangoFilterBackend to filter my products by some details that are different based on their category, but I get the error "'ProductFilter' object is not callable".
My filtering works fine when I don't limit the choices based on chosen category, but when I try limitting them I get the above error.

these are my models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    desc = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()


class ProductEnumProperty(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_enum_properties')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ProductPropertyState(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(ProductEnumProperty, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_property_states')
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.property.name} - {self.state}'


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='products')
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    props = models.ManyToManyField(ProductPropertyState,
                                   )
```

For example:
Category:
jeans---------->ProductEnumProperty:flyer type----------->(ProductPropertyStates:(1-buttons 2-zipper))

filters.py:

```
class ProductFilter(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = {
            'price': ['gt', 'lt'],
            'props': ['exact'],
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        category_slug = kwargs['category_slug']
        del kwargs['category_slug']
        super(ProductFilter, self).__init__()
        self.filters['props'].extra.update(
            {'queryset': ProductPropertyState.objects.filter(property__category__slug=category_slug)})
```

views.py:

```
class ProductByCategory(ListAPIView):
    def get_category(self):
        category_slug = self.kwargs.get('category_slug')
        return category_slug

    serializer_class = ProductMiniSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = ProductFilter(category_slug=get_category)
    search_fields = ['title', 'desc', 'category__title']
    ordering_fields = ['price', 'title']
```

I think there must be something wrong with my way of passing the kwargs.
does anyone know a solution?

I also tried giving category or category_slug as a paramether to the **init** in ProductFilter.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing kwargs here:
`super(ProductFilter, self).__init__()` - as you are when you declare `__init__`. So the initialization might have issues.

Looking at DRF documentation, you can simply modify queryset on `class ProductByCategory(ListAPIView):` like here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#overriding-the-initial-queryset - `get_queryset` method, so it will remove the problematic filter modification.

Answer (score 0):

you should override a get method in your ProductByCategory Class in views like this

```
  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        objs = self.get_queryset()
        objs = self.filter_queryset(objs).order_by("admission_date")
        ser = self.serializer_class(objs, many=True)
        return ser
```